# Webscraping using Excel VB getElementsByTagName("a") Only Works Some Of The Time

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the following code to successfully pull in data on email into Excel:

```
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each Link In ElementCol   

        If InStr(Link, "mailto:") Then

            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = Link

            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Select

            MyCol = MyCol + 1

        End If

    Next 'email address loop
```

This relates to:

[image]

However, I can't use similar code to pull in the name:

[image]

I have tried `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName`  and I have tried changing `html.` to `doc.` and `Text.` because I thought the issue could be that an email address is a hyperlink so `html.` is appropriate but a name is plain text so I should use something else? I am getting Object Required error. 
EDIT: Thanks for the comments guys. Below is my full code. I am scraping the British House of Commons website for MP details. The URL has a random number so I am brute-forcing the URL, trying every number from 1 to 5000. I have highlighted the non-working part (which is still not working when I try the new code suggested here) Example URL: https://members.parliament.uk/member/4212/contact

```
Sub scrapeHyperlinksWebsite()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim Link As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim erow As Long
Dim MyURL As String
Dim MyRow, MyCol As Integer
Dim Constituency As String
Dim coll As IHTMLElementCollection ' suggestion from Stackoverflow


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'clear existing data
Call clearRows


Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False

'initiate variable
URL_Number = 0

'static elements:
URL_Str1 = "https://members.parliament.uk/member/"
URL_Str2 = "/contact"

'Begin loop down page

For MyRow = 2 To 5000

    URL_Number = URL_Number + 1

    MyCol = 1

    MyURL = URL_Str1 & URL_Number & URL_Str2

    ie.navigate MyURL

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading website…"
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ie.document

    Range("L2") = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML


    'Get MP email addresses
    MyCol = 1

    Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each Link In ElementCol   'find emails in each site

        If InStr(Link, "mailto:") Then

            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = Link

            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Select

            MyCol = MyCol + 1

        End If

    Next 'email address loop


 MyCol = 3

 'Get MP phone numbers

    Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each Link In ElementCol   'find emails in each site

        If InStr(Link, "tel:") Then

            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = Link

            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Select

            MyCol = MyCol + 1

        End If

    Next 'email address loop




 'Get Constituency - This section is not working
' MyCol = 5
'
'    Set coll = html.getElementsByTagName("h1")
'
'    For Each Link In coll   'find emails in each site
'
'        If InStr(Link, "Contact") Then
'
'            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = coll
'
'            Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Select
'
'            MyCol = MyCol + 1
'
'        End If
'
'    Next 'email address loop
'

 'above section is not working






Next ' main loop





Set ie = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""









'Tidy data

Cells.Select

    With Selection

        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom

        .Orientation = 0

        .AddIndent = False

        .IndentLevel = 0

        .ShrinkToFit = False

        .ReadingOrder = xlContext

        .MergeCells = False

    End With

    With Selection

        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

        .Orientation = 0

        .AddIndent = False

        .IndentLevel = 0

        .ShrinkToFit = False

        .ReadingOrder = xlContext

        .MergeCells = False

    End With

    Selection.RowHeight = 15

    Range("D1").Select






End Sub


Sub clearRows()

Range("A2:M50000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You showed what worked, but you have NOT shown your code that doesn't work

Comment: Dim coll As IHTMLElementCollection: Set coll = html.getElementsByTagName("H1")

Comment: Can you include the start of your code and the url (if public)? The html should be shared by copy pasting the relevant html and inserting using snippet tool via [edit]; not as as an image. Then also show the desired output. Did you really want emails going across columns rather than rows? Presumably you want name:email pairs ?

Comment: @QHarr Each MP has 0 to 2 emails and 1 to 2 phone numbers. I want the emails and phone numbers going across each row for the same MP, then move down a row and pull in the next set and so on. It is no good unless I can also pull in the names and constituencies though, so they should also be on the same row. Where my generated URLs don't match any MP, excel returns a blank row, so I will add some code to delete the blank rows.

Comment: @MacroMarc I tried your code but I am getting the same errors. If I comment out the IF statement, it returns "[object HTMLHeadingElement]". I also tried looking in h2, which has the format "Contact "[MP Name]". I know my code above refers to h1 but I corrected it and still got the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The code to get the H1s works fine. There is no contact there, and so you can try the below:

MyCol = 5
Set coll = html.getElementsByTagName("h1")
For Each Link In coll   'find emails in each site
    If InStr(Link, "Contact") Then
        Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value = Link.innerText
         MyCol = MyCol + 1
    End If
Next Link    'MP Name Loop
```